# How do you count second level depth childs in xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, count

I have an xml var with this content:

```
    <deelnemers>        
    <deelnemer id="timka">  
        <actID>0</actID>
    <actID>1</actID>
    </deelnemer>    
    <deelnemer id="hop">    
    <actID>0</actID>
    <actID>1</actID>
    <actID>3</actID>
    </deelnemer>    
    </deelnemers>;
```

How do I count how many `<actID>`'s there are for every `<deelnemer>`?

And how do I provide a datagrid with an xml var?

Comment: What have you done so far? There are tons of information online for populating a datagrid from XML, for example [Passing data to a DataGrid control @ help.adobe.com](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-8000.html)

Comment: I only found info using XML-lists

Answer (score 0):

You can count using this code

```
XMLID.deelnemer..actID.length();
```

http://www.almondlab.jp/notes/833 (Japanese)